# How to upload a django project to my host?

Tags: python, django, apache, host

I have a django project.

How can I upload this project to my host?

I have followed the steps from [this page](http://wiki.helionet.org/Django) but still getting a below error:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@snip77.heliohost.org and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

My website is : [snip77.heliohost.org](http://snip77.heliohost.org)

Comment: The recommended place to start from the django site is using [mod_wsgi](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/)

Comment: Did you look in the error log, as recommended by that message?

Comment: Have a look at the error log. If you have a VPS and using apache should be under /etc/log if you have a shared host account look in your control panel. CPanel or plesk for example have a section for your error logs